# AngularJS controller not communicating with Spring controllers

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm attempting to utilize a REST API which is created using Spring by using AngularJS controllers. All I want to do, is send the credentials from the form using AngularJS to the Spring controllers in the back end; however, they don't seem to be communicating at all. Whenever I push the login button, the page simply refreshes. I placed loggers in the Spring controller I'm attempting to call, but they never print anything out which means the controller is never being called.

AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module('landing', [ 'ngRoute' ])
        .controller('authentication',
          function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {
          $scope.credentials = {};
          $scope.login = function() {
            $http.post('http://localhost:8090/login', $.param($scope.credentials), {
              headers : {
                "content-type" : "application/json"
              }
            }
          };
        });
```

The Spring controller I'm attempting to utilize:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessUser> login(@RequestBody BusinessUser inputUser) {
        logger.info(inputUser.getUsername());
        logger.info(inputUser.getPassword());
        BusinessUser requestedUser = businessUserService.findByUsername(inputUser.getUsername());
        if(requestedUser != null)
            if(BCrypt.checkpw(inputUser.getPassword(), requestedUser.getPassword()))
                return new ResponseEntity<>(requestedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Lastly, here's the form:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" ng-app="landing">
   <div id="home" class="border-shadow">
        <div class="container-fluid container-background-color">
            <div class="row border-shadow">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <h2 class="heading-margin main-color"><img class="imagesize" src="images/icon.png"/><b>Test Company</b></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5" ng-controller="authentication">
                    <form role="form" ng-submit="login()">              
                        <div class="form-group row row-margin">
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.username" placeholder="Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">       
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                <a href="#" class="forget"> Forgot Your Password</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I can send requests using a Chrome add on called "Postman" and the results come back perfectly, so it's an AngularJS problem. Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT** This is a Spring Boot project by the way.

Comment: Did you check CORS errors in your browser ? If you didn't you should take a look to this : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: where are you handling the callback of the $http?

Comment: you don't need to use `$.param` if you are sending as a payload I guess...

Comment: @MickaëlB I tried adding `@CrossOrigin` but it doesn't work. I can send requests and receive proper responses using Postman (Chrome REST extension) so I'm not sure if it's an issue with Spring. Also, to answer the other two, I'm not handling the call back of `$http` because right now they aren't communicating at all. I want the loggers I put in the Spring controller to print something, but they never do. I removed `$.param` and nothing changed.

Comment: Uhmm, the callback maybe can help you to track what is the problem.
personally i'll change that ng-submit and insted use a ng-click on the button calling the function of your login

Comment: Also i think that your function isn't being executed, check it

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I had  ng-click previously, but changed it to ng-submit to see if that would solve the issue. I just switched it back to ng-click and it still doesn't work. If it helps, I'm using Eclipse, I installed the AngularJS plugin for Eclipse (the ng attributes are dark blue and have documentation when you hover over them, so they're set up correctly).

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Should I add a variable that prints out whenever the function is called? Like an attribute on the screen? That's what I'm thinking as well. For some reason, the function isn't being called.

Comment: @JakeMiller yeah, just add a `console.log()` to see in the web brownser console if is being called

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval It says there's no module named "landing" but I named my module "landing"? Hmm

Comment: Are all your js file referenced on your html? did you use the `ng-app` to refer your module?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Currently, the script is in the same file as the HTML. The script is in `<script>` tags in the `<head>`. In the form I posted above, I reference the module using `ng-app` with the name "landing" but it says unknown module landing. Not sure why it's saying that because the module is named landing, the script is in the header before the `ng-app` reference is used, and there's no errors in Eclipse.